# How can I create new factorization projects?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I found many factorization projects in the internet : Mersenne-primes, Fermat-primes, Cunningham-project , Proth-number-search and many more.

If I want to create a new fatorization project :

> 1) How can I find out if such a project is already in progress (Of course,
>        I can search with google first, but maybe google does not find an
>        existing project because I named it wronlgy) ?
>
> 2) How can I suggest to open a new project and submit the factorizations, I
>        already found ?

I found this site : https://primes.utm.edu/ , where prime curious and prime numbers can be submitted, but I doubt I can create a new project on this site.

Comment: There's also factordb.com. Not quite what you're looking for but it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I know this already, but thanks for the info.